# Multiple hashtags in URL

Tags: php, jquery, hashtag

I have this code to access tabs by URL hashtag

```
example.com/app.php?id=55#tehn
```

Code for hashtags

```
      $(function(){
      var hash = window.location.hash;
      hash && $('ul.nav a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
      $('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
        $(this).tab('show');
        var scrollmem = $('body').scrollTop() || $('html').scrollTop();
        window.location.hash = this.hash;
        $('html,body').scrollTop(scrollmem);


        });
  });
```

This link will open tab with list of items. Every item has own ID #1, #2, #3 etc. When I click on that item I append html div to show via jquery.

This is the code for that:

```
    $('.clicka').on('click', function() {
    var data = {
        pid: $(this).data('pid')
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'includes/content/pozicija_info.php',
        async:true,
        data: data,

        success: function(response) {

            $('#prikazi_operacije').html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Is it possible to access some item directly by URL in this format:

```
example.com/app.php?id=55#tehn#1
```

When I click on item, URL changes from

```
example.com/app.php?id=55#tehn
```

To

```
example.com/app.php?id=55#1
```

Comment: Have you considered using the build-in URL parser of most browsers (if not build-in, use a polyfill)?
 https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Comment: I think you need to use regex : https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-basic-regex-selector-examples/